# setTimeout() and remove() doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
function flash(msg) {
  var _id = $('#flash_notice__');
  if( _id.length > 0 ) {
   _id.html(msg); 
  } else {
    $('<div id="flash_notice__">'+ msg +'</div>').appendTo('body');
    //$('body').append('<div id="flash_notice__">'+ msg +'</div>');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    _id.fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).remove(); //or _id.remove();
    });
  }, 2500);
}
```

First time (on refresh) the message (msg) remain on page, then when flash() run again, works good.
I think, when _id exist .remove() it's working, but when is create the  the message it's still on screen.
What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've basically answered your own question:

> I think, when _id exist .remove() it's working, but when is create the the message it's still on screen

If you look at your code, the variable `_id` only exists when the message is onscreen already. In the case you create it, that variable does not point to anything:

```
var _id = $('#flash_notice__');
...
} else {
  $('<div id="flash_notice__">'+ msg +'</div>').appendTo('body');
}
```

Change your code to:

```
function flash(msg) {
  var _id = $('#flash_notice__');
  if( _id.length > 0 ) {
   _id.html(msg); 
  } else {
    _id = $('<div id="flash_notice__">'+ msg +'</div>').appendTo('body');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    _id.fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).remove(); //or _id.remove();
    });
  }, 2500);
}
```

Example with element already on page: http://jsfiddle.net/GyUhB/
Example with no element on page: http://jsfiddle.net/GyUhB/1/

Comment: It's working, thanks, but I can't understand. `var _id = $('#flash_notice__');` is outside of if condition... if I keep my code and just replace "_id.fadeOut(500,...)" with "$('#flash_notice__').fadeOut(500, ...)" it's working very good.

Comment: @user2039290 - that line of code runs *before* you create the element in the `else` branch of the logic. Therefore when you try to use the variable `_id` later on, it doesn't reference any object.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
function flash(msg) {
  var _id = $('#flash_notice__');
  if( !_id.length ) {
    _id = $('<div id="flash_notice__">'+ msg +'</div>').appendTo('body');
  } else {
   _id.html(msg).show();
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    _id.fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 2500);
}
```

Note: `.hide()` not `.remove()`, so _flash_notice is available to be reused next time round. Otherwise a new _flash_notice will be created every time.